# How do you configure text replacements using Keymando?

Tags: keymando

I want to do simple text replacements/spelling corrections using Keymando, eg. when I type "js", I want it to expand to "John Smith".

The Keymando home page has a short video showing this capability - they call it Abbreviations - but I don't see how to configure it.  I did download the abbrev.rb file and place it in my Keymando /plugins directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you downloaded the abbrev plugin did you setup any abbreviations?

```
abbrev 'nname', 'John Smith'
```